# Textbox Width Manipulation - Not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want restrict the space in empty text box and text-area box below Code is not working in mobile its working in desktop please check and help on this

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type=text],textarea").keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which === 32 && !this.value.length) {
                return e.which !== 32;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<input type="text" maxlength='25'>
<textarea></textarea>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector will cancel the spacebar in **ALL textboxes** and **textareas** on your page. Are you sure?

If you are, then you can use the `keydown` event, and `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the space bar.

```
$("input[type=text],textarea").keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '32') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```